# How to submit through webhooks a table with borders?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I can post tables but it's without borders..

```
curl -X POST "https://eu.yourcircuit.com/rest/v2/webhooks/incoming/randomID" -H "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "{  \"text\": \"<table><tr><td>1<\/td><td>2<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>haha<\/td><td>hihi<\/td><\/tr><\/table>\" }"
```

The table should have a border, but with the parameter `border="1"` I receive following error:

> {"errorDescription":"the request contains invalid
>   data","validationErrors":["Cannot validate the request parameter with
>   name ::= [content]","The request parameter with name ::= [content] is
>   forbidden by ANTISAMY"],"errorCode":"400"}

So how can I fix this? I saw a printscreen form Unify itself where the table has borders..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are not supported in Circuit. For supported formats in Circuit see https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_addTextItem.

Having said that, simple tables are currently not blocked by the HTML validator.

The reason your example is not working is because the html is not valid. Use this content with correct opening and closing tags.

```
curl -X POST "https://eu.yourcircuit.com/rest/v2/webhooks/incoming/randomID" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "{ \"text\": \"<table border="1"><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>\" }"
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Any ideas why it's working on the circuit desktop app, firefox, chrome but not on the android mobile app?

Comment: @BraamVanHavermaet You can open a new question, meanwhile accept the answer if it was helpful and answered this question.

Comment: @BraamVanHavermaet as mentioned tables are not supported. Mobile clients don't render tables correctly.